# How can I view user agent specific stylesheets in FF?

Tags: css, firefox

Chrome easily lets me see the user agent stylesheets as part of Chrome Developer Tools.

[image: Chrome Developer Tools]

Is there a way to view this in FireFox's console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found what I was looking for.  It is a small checkbox in the console.  I am on version 65.0.1.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The computed styles tab that has been mentioned is subtly different, since it shows the computed values(e.g converts em to px). If you want to see the actual user agent style sheet rules, you can check "show browser styles" under settings.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this used to be a feature, and I have [proof](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1230675) (as you can see, malcolmi was asking what the user agent stylesheets were)!
I haven't found a way as of now (yet)but in the meantime, you can use [Firefox's default styles](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/layout/style/res/html.css) as a reference.